# Rewrite, hide extensions .php (Internal Error)

Tags: php

the rewrite is working (envasionsworld.net/login.php is -> envasionsworld.net/login) but when i enter (envasionsworld.net/loginasmdhaosdhma) it says 500 Internal Server Error.

Does somebody know why?

Code:

```
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: _“Does somebody know why?”_ - yes, your server’s error log. Please _always_ go check that upfront, when you’re dealing with a 500 error.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, im new here xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the remove .php extention to the vhost file.

you could place it in a .htaccess file and add this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Request by @FionnRe:Redirect /login.php to /Login
    below `RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]`
    add: `RewriteRule ^login.php$ /Login`

Comment: to fix .htaccess. goto your vhost file and add the following `</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/html/yoursite.com/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

Comment: try my .htaccess fix and let me know. What server are you using ? or is it xampp localhost ?

Comment: Sorry, but where can i find that file ? c:

Comment: Debian 8, Apache2

Comment: location: "/etc/apache2/sites-available/yoursite.com.conf"

Comment: link it to your public_html folder not /www/

Comment: Nice now it works, but i can access login.php it should rewrite to /login is that possible?

Comment: i will add the redirect to my answer. if my answer helped and is correct please mark answer as correct.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: simply mark the tick that's below the down arrow by my answer

Comment: done. the problem is, that i want to redirect envasionsworld.net/anyfile.php -> envasionsworld.net/anyfile

Comment: now in envasionsworld.net root directory create a .htaccess file and add `RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^anyfile.php$ /anyfile`

Comment: yeah but i want to do it for each file

Comment: `RewriteRule ^anyfile.php$ /anyfile` gives me an internal server error

Comment: try and add a slash "/" before anyfile.php eg: `^/anyfile.php$`